# What does the second "of" mean in this sentence? "... because I regard it as of considerable importance."

Tags: grammar, meaning

The entire sentence:
"I have set that part of the judgment out in detail because I regard it as of considerable importance."

This sentence is from Lexico.
I wonder if the second "of" can be dropped.
Should I regard "of considerable importance" as an adjective phrase?

Comment: Importance is a noun; you cannot drop the 'of' before 'considerable'.

Comment: No, because then you would have to use; I regard it **as having considerable importance**.

Comment: _Of importance_ is just another way of saying _important_.